# installing systemc on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemc

I am a beginner.
I'm installing systemc231 on Ubuntu and I have done this:

```
tar -xzvf systemc-2.3.1.tgz
cd systemc-2.3.1
sudo mkdir /usr/local/systemc231
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
export cxx="<compiler>"
export cxx=g++
export cxx=clang++
setevn cxx g++
```

It answered :`command not found`
Then I continued:

```
../configure
```

It took a moment and checked something but finally it answered :

```
 Configure:error: in /home/Ubuntu/systemc-2.3.1/objdir':

 Configure:error:c++compiler cannot create executables see 'config.log' for more details
```

And then I continued :

```
make
```

And it answered :

```
make:*** no targets specified no makefile found. Stop.
```

Now what can l do?
This is the link of systemc231 file and I have used its readme and install files for  writing the commands :

http://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/systemc/systemc-2.3.1.tgz

Comment: It seems that you mess up everything. Which tutorial you followed ? can you attach the link with the question ?

Comment: You might want to ask such kind of questions on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: I have added the link to my codes.

Comment: command not found: setevn cxx g++ => setenv cxx g++ (small typo in setenv)

Comment: Could you try just the command 'g++' to find out if you have the GNU C++ compiler installed?  You can do the same for 'clang++'

Comment: Thank you all, now I have an error that is 'compiler not supported '.how can I fix this?

Comment: time for an update of your commands.  What is the last 'export CXX' you have done.  And what about running that command itself.

Comment: you are right vemaete, I have followed your instruction, I  used the command 'g++' and I found out that I have the GNU C++ compiler installed. I have tried systemc220, systemc230 and systemc231.

Comment: I think may be I have not downloaded all the necessary software, don't you think so?

Comment: should it not be 'export CXX=g++' (capitals).  Don't do another export!.  And check with 'env | grep CXX' if the variable is set.

Comment: thank again, the problem was solved. now after' make' I see these messages:

Comment: ../../../libtool: line 1153: g++: command not found
make[3]: *** [sc_attribute.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Downloads/systemc-2.3.0/objdir/src/sysc/kernel'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Downloads/systemc-2.3.0/objdir/src/sysc'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Downloads/systemc-2.3.0/objdir/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, you use export to set environmental variables. In other Linux distributions, you use setenv. You only need one of those commands. do a command to figure out if g++ is installed

```
which g++
```

If it doesnt return something like

```
/usr/bin/g++
```

Then its not installed, just install it with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then check again with **which**
You created an installation directory /usr/local/systemc231 you need to specify that you want to install systemc therein in the configure command. Find a tutorial about [setting up systemc and eclipse configuration in ubuntu on my blog](http://karibe.co.ke/2014/02/setting-up-systemc-and-eclipse-for-c-hardware-simulation/)